# css and sprites - unexpected result

Tags: css, sprite

What am I doing wrong here? I cannot get the sprites to work correctly. When I inspect the element it is not the right height or width. I have gotten sprites to work having a container div with the background image, but I don't think having a wrapper is correct in this type of situation.

Here is what I'm trying to do..

```
<html>
<style>
.bottomtable{display:block;}
.bottomtable .close {float: right;margin-right:5px;margin-top:25px;display:inline;position:relative;background-image:url('http://www.freeimagehosting.net/o2gz4');background-position:-278px -18px;height:7px;width:7px;}
.bottomtable .close a {height:7px;width:7px;}
.bottomtable .titletext{text-align: right;float: right;margin-right:5px;margin-top:-20px;display:block;}
.bottomtable h5{margin:0;padding:0;font-size: 14px;font-weight:normal;display: inline;}
.bottomtable ul {display:block;padding:5px;margin:0;}
.bottomtable li {list-style-type:none;padding:10px;margin:0;height:75px;display:block;}
.bottomtable li a{text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;display:block;margin-bottom:5px;}
.bottomtable li a span{display:block;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;margin:2px 0 4px;}
.bottomtable ul img {display:inline;float:left;margin-top:-2px;margin-right:20px;}
</style>
<body>
<div class="bottomtable">
<ul>
    <li><h5><a href="#">some title</a></h5><a href="javascript://close" class="close" title="">&nbsp;</a>this is some text here..............<div style="clear: right;"></div>                        </li>
    <li><h5><a href="#">some title</a></h5><a href="javascript://close" class="close" title="">&nbsp;</a>this is some text here..............<div style="clear: right;"></div>    </li>
    <li><h5><a href="#">some title</a></h5><a href="javascript://close" class="close" title="">&nbsp;</a>this is some text here..............<div style="clear: right;"></div>    </li>
    <li><h5><a href="#">some title</a></h5><a href="javascript://close" class="close" title="">&nbsp;</a>this is some text here..............<div style="clear: right;"></div>    </li>

</ul>
</div>
</style>
</html>
```

`

All you can see is a small portion of the X.

If I don't put that blank space between the link, it doesn't show anything at all... There has to be something I am just doing wrong. What is it? I have inspected tuns of sites and they don't seem to need that space in there.

Comment: Which background sprite from http://www.freeimagehosting.net/o2gz4 you want to display??

Comment: What on Earth is going on here, why do you have the divs with clear right? I think you need to go back and learn a few things about CSS and the way it works. 

If you can tell us your desired outcome, we can help you re-write that CSS :)

Comment: I am trying to do the small X.

Comment: I have the clear right because of the float. Aren't you supposed to clear your floats?

Comment: Yes, but after all the floats have been put inot effect, this is a lot more complicated than it needs to be. What do you want it to look like? :)

Comment: That first answer I checked is how I want it to look. I have that inside of a wrapper div so it's only about 450 width. When I try to add to live environment it looks wrong again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing works. Please check with this:

```
<html>
   <style>
     .bottomtable{display:block;}
     .bottomtable .close {background-image:url("http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/o2gz4.png");background-position: -278px -18px;color: #FFFFFF;display: inline;float: right;height: 10px;margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 10px;position: relative;width: 11px;}
     .bottomtable .close a {height:7px;width:7px;}
     .bottomtable .titletext{text-align: right;float: right;margin-right:5px;margin-top:-20px;display:block;}
     .bottomtable h5{margin:0;padding:0;font-size: 14px;font-weight:normal;display: inline;}
     .bottomtable ul {display:block;padding:5px;margin:0;}
     .bottomtable li {list-style-type:none;padding:10px;margin:0;height:75px;display:block;}
     .bottomtable li a{text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;display:block;margin-bottom:5px;}
     .bottomtable li a span{display:block;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;margin:2px       0 4px;}
     .bottomtable ul img {display:inline;float:left;margin-top:-2px;margin-right:20px;}
</style>
<body>
   <div class="bottomtable">
     <ul>
        <li><h5><a href="#">some title</a></h5><a href="javascript://close" class="close" title="">&nbsp;</a>this is some text here..............<div style="clear: right;"></div>                                  </li>
       <li><h5><a href="#">some title</a></h5><a href="javascript://close" class="close" title="">&nbsp;</a>this is some text here..............<div style="clear: right;"></div>    </li>
       <li><h5><a href="#">some title</a></h5><a href="javascript://close" class="close" title="">&nbsp;</a>this is some text here..............<div style="clear: right;"></div>    </li>
       <li><h5><a href="#">some title</a></h5><a href="javascript://close" class="close" title="">&nbsp;</a>this is some text here..............<div style="clear: right;"></div>    </li>

     </ul>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Your background image path is wrong.You have to specify the complete image url which is http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/o2gz4.png

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample ( with your code ) http://jsfiddle.net/vFLRe/26/

```
<html> 
<style> 
.bottomtable .close {float:right;margin-right:5px;margin-top:25px;background-image:url('http://www.freeimagehosting.net/o2gz4');background-position:-278px -18px;height:25px;width:25px;display:block;border:1px solid black;} 
.bottomtable .close a {height:25px;width:25px;} 
</style> 
<body> 
<div class="bottomtable"> 
<ul> 
    <li><h5><a href="#">some title</a></h5><a href="javascript://close" class="close" title=""></a>this is some text here..............<div style="clear: right;"></div>                        </li>  
</ul> 
    </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```